# Blocking of Main Thread in Firebase Chat Listener "Save" Operation in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Firebase Chat in Swift 5.0 When I do get all the messages
from the local database then if the number of messages are larger then
this firebase message listener call-backs blocking the Main Thread for sometime due to save operation.

I have already tried adding the background thread on code but it seems not to be worked. Below is my some code snippets.

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
      self.setChatMessageListener()
}

// this call is already done on background thread
   func setChatMessageListener () {
        removeChatMessageListener()
        FirebaseUtils.instance.getChatMessages(chatMasterId: chatMasterId).observe(.childAdded) {
            (snapshot) in
// I want this call to be done on background thread how can i do that?
// this get called for each message so main thread is blocking here
            self.updateChatMessage(snapshot: snapshot)
        }
    }


 func updateChatMessage (snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        if let chatMessage = getChatMessage(snapshot: snapshot) {
            DatabaseManager.getInstance().getDatabaseWriteManager().saveData(realmObject: chatMessage) {
                (success) in
                self.loadMessages(chatMessageId: chatMessage.chatMessageId)
            }
        }
        else {
            self.loadMessages()
        }
    }
```

How could i make self.updateChatMessage() operation on background thread?

Comment: In my assumption, you need to go through the `SnapshotListener` on FirebaseChat. Try with this library or it's related - https://github.com/omrobbie/ios-firebase-chat. You can achieve your desired output in background mode.

Comment: Why you used local database for getting messages from Firebase. You can get those messages using Firebase snapshot. And further input and output messages were handled by built in snap shot listener from Firebase. You need go through related this.

Comment: i have used snapshot only the problem i am facing in the storing of messages in realm db, which using main thread

Comment: Then you must try with query for loading 50 messages like as a pagination instead of loading bulk messages. So go through how to form the Query on Firebase. It will overcome your blocking issue.

Comment: yes that will be the suitable option for now, tx

Comment: How did you determine that your calls are blocking? All network operations that the Firebase client performs are done **off** the main thread. It then calls your callback/closure back in the main/UI thread again, so that you can update the UI. In most situations you should have to do anything for this yourself. The only cases I know where this might be necessary are: 1) when you're retrieving *a lot* of data, so that even passing it to your callback becomes too slow, 2) when you are performing significant post-processing on the data in your own code.

Comment: @Fri got your point tx

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen: Solved the issue by changing the message loading logics

Comment: In general, you don't need this `DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async` at all. The code in the question is a bit incomplete but as along as your UI calls are done within Firebase function closures, the UI won't be affected.